# Как работают инструменты командной строки?

Tags: теория, терминал

Допустим, я установил Python. У меня в терминале появилась команда python. Но как это произошло? Установочный файл питона создал в директории bin новый исполняемый файл? Если да, то как?
И вообще, как разработчики интерпретаторов и платформ вроде Node.js и Cordova добавляют в командную оболчку (терминал) новые команды? Используется ли Bash?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Переменная **PATH** содержит список директорий, в которых операционная система пытается искать исполняемые файлы, если пользователь при запуске не указал явно путь к нужному исполняемому файлу.

Давайте представим себе, что на компьютере с операционной системой Windows установлено две разных версии интерпретатора языка программирования Python. Это можно сделать, если установить их в разные директории, например, *C:\Python27* и *C:\Python34*. Исполняемый файл для обоих версий называется *python.exe*.

Для того, чтобы запустить исполняемый файл нужной версии, можно указать полный путь к нему, например, *C:\Python34\python.exe:*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но каждый раз указывать полный путь лень, да ещё и помнить его надо.

Альтернатива – добавить в переменную окружения PATH путь к директории, где находится этот исполняемый файл, и тогда его можно будет запускать, указывая только имя. А чтобы узнать, где он (по мнению операционной системы) находится, можно использовать команду *where* в операционной системе Windows либо команду *which* в операционной системе Linux или MacOS.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Более подробно, в [оригинальной](http://barancev.github.io/what-is-path-env-var/) статье.

Comment: Добавлю: помимо `PATH` существует ещё и раздел реестра [`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ee872121(v=vs.85).aspx#appPaths), где можно указывать отображение конкретных имён на конкретные пути (плюс модификацию `PATH` для этой программы). И сдаётся мне, что эти имена не обязательно должны совпадать с реальными именами файлов.

Comment: Не знал про which в линуксе, всегда использовал whereis

Answer (score 0):

"Команды терминала" это и в самом деле просто исполняемые файлы в оглавлениях, которые перечислены в Вашей environment переменной **PATH**.

Конечно, есть еще встроенные в `bash` (или другой интерпретатор командной строки) команды, например `umask` (это обязательно, поскольку меняет состояние самого интерпретатора) или `echo` (для эффективности).

Команда `python`, которую Вы упоминаете, расположена в оглавлении `/usr/local/bin`, кстати, Вы всегда можете выяснить это, набрав

```
avp@avp-ubu1:~$ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

и представляет собой

```
avp@avp-ubu1:~$ file /usr/bin/python
/usr/bin/python: symbolic link to python2.7
avp@avp-ubu1:~$ ll /usr/bin/python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Dec 10  2015 /usr/bin/python -> python2.7*
avp@avp-ubu1:~$
```

в конечном итоге

```
avp@avp-ubu1:~$ ll /usr/bin/python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3546104 Jul  2 22:05 /usr/bin/python2.7*
avp@avp-ubu1:~$ file /usr/bin/python2.7
/usr/bin/python2.7: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=dadc6dc447374ae242ac392c67c898e3d5f49972, stripped
avp@avp-ubu1:~$
```

исполнимый двоичный (т.е. непосредственно исполняемый CPU) файл.

Его создал там установщик `apt-get` (или `yum`, зависит от версии Linux), исполняя команды процедуры установки,  находящейся в составе пакета (файл .deb (или .rpm)), содержащего python.

Какая конкретно команда непосредственно в процедуре установки создала файл /usr/bin/python2.7 можно сказать только раскрыв пакет и посмотрев текст скрипта установки. Можно предположить, что `cpio` (или даже просто cp, или tar), но это не принципиально, поскольку по сути, просто один из файлов пакета был скопирован в нужное оглавление, а потом на него были установлены необходимые привилегии.

Про вопрос, а используется ли в этом процессе bash, в общем можно сказать то же самое (imho скорее всего да, используется) -- надо смотреть содержимое пакета.